# access to data via login-server with ftp-client

Tags: ssh, login, filezilla

I have a simple question. Until now I was using FileZilla to shift my data via ssh from my home computer to the institutes server. At the new institute I have to access my local data on my computer there via a login server. Is it possible with FileZilla or an other client to have also in this case the possibility to shift the data from my remote computer at the institute to my home computer without "seeing" the transfer via the login server? Because now I'm using the shell, login on login-server, then on my remote computer. From there I send the files to the login-server and then home.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution seems to be a VPN client connected to the login-server.

E.g.: Use Cisco-VPN client. Connect to login-server with the settings given by your institute. Use FileZilla to connect directly to your remote computer via sftp.

Comment: Mark your answer as solved. To help other users, editing this answer with how you set-up the server would be helpful.

Comment: @emb1995: allowed to mark in 17h...